# Scala: inferring a type parameter from class name

Tags: scala, reflection

Here is what I am trying to do -

```
val classType = someMagicCode("com.mydomain.SomeClass")
someMethod[classType](someArgs)
```

Is it possible to do this in Scala? If yes, how?